# JNI some methods throw UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Have you ever come across something like this? I have a JNI class and dll from a company form some hardware programming and I use that to develop an application interface for the hardware. I test deploy the application and then I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError from some of the methods. Essentially, the application is half working. Some methods called from the JNI class works fine, others don't. But keep in mind the dll may link to other dlls since there were several others required for the setup of the hardware but only one requiring loadlibrary(). Any ideas where the UnsatisfiedLinkError maybe coming from?

Comment: Do you have all the required files for that dll. May be you are missing some dll's which your main dll is looking for.

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes I do have all the files. The test deploy setup isn't different from the machine I developed it on. But just in case, is it possible to get that kind error where only some methods are throwing the exception if some of the dlls are missing?

Comment: Yes. Because you mentioned that half of the application is working. Then part of the interfaces are working properly. Part of them are failing because of some dependencies. If you have the code it's easy to track down.

Comment: `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when loading libraries or when calling methods? They mean different things.

Comment: @EJP UnsatisfiedLinkError when Calling methods.@Karthick Do you mean the code for the C files one that created the JNI dll? I'll try to check if its available.

Comment: If it's when calling methods, it's because the C method name and the Java method name no longer agree. You have changed one of them since you ran javah, or changed the Java package, or not included the .h file in the .c file.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, I contacted the vendor and it seems that I got an updated version of the dll where in the 2 methods that threw the exception had an extra variable output added to it. So all I did was get the updated source file for the Java and updated the method there accordingly. Thanks again!